# Call method in QMainWindow from QDialog

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am running this to show a dialog window from main:

```
void SQLWindow::on_action_4_triggered()
{ 
   HeaderList window; 
   window.show(); 
   window.exec(); 
}
```

Here I am trying to connect a saveButtonClicked() to the SLOT in the Main Window:

```
HeaderList::HeaderList(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent), ui(new Ui::HeaderList) 
{ 
   connect(this, SIGNAL(saveButtonClicked()), SQLWindow, SLOT(hideColumns())); 

   ui->setupUi(this); 
}
```

but getting an error: "expected primary-expression before ',' token" which points at "SQLWindow". I am doing this wrong, obviously. Any ideas how to call a method in Main Window from Dialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third parameter in connect(...) needs to be a pointer to an instance. Just change the signature of your HeaderList's constructor and add the SQLWindow as parameter (+ use the newer connect method call as TheDarkKnight mentioned):

```
HeaderList::HeaderList(SQLWindow *parent) : QDialog(parent), ui(new Ui::HeaderList)
{
    connect(this, &HeaderList::saveButtonClicked, parent, &SQLWindow::hideColumns);

    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

In the header file, it would be a good idea to make the HeaderList constructor explicit and not overload parent with nullptr:

```
class HeaderList
{
public:
    explicit HeaderList(SQLWindow *parent);

    //...
};
```

Pass the SQLWindow to your HeaderList (and omit show() as thuga mentioned):

```
void SQLWindow::on_action_4_triggered()
{
    HeaderList window(this);
    window.exec();
}
```

Comment: Also `window.show(); window.exec();` makes no sense. You can just call `window.exec();`. Though I would make `window` a member variable of `SQLWindow` class and just call `show`.

Comment: As the OP is using Qt5, I recommend using it's newer `connect` method, which provides compile-time errors. This would be *connect(this, &HeaderList::saveButtonClicked, parent, &SQLWindow::hideColumns);*

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks for answer. I've got an error in "explicit HeaderList(SQLWindow *parent);" – "expected ')' before '*' token"

Comment: @Edward You forgot the pointer * and you have to forward declare SQLWindow and include it in the HeaderList implementation

Comment: @ChrisG Pointer was in place, but, yep, I forgot to include SQLWindow in the implementation. Thanks, it works.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Thanks for the tip (:

Answer (score 3):

connect the signal other way round like this:

```
class HeaderList
{
public:
    explicit HeaderList(QWidget *parent);

signals:
    void saveButtonClicked();
};
```

now in `SQLWindow`

```
void SQLWindow::on_action_4_triggered()
{ 
   HeaderList window; 
   connect(&window, SIGNAL(saveButtonClicked()), this, SLOT(hideColumns()));
   window.exec(); 
}
```

Comment: Didn't think about calling "connect" when initialising, pretty elegant. Thanks for answer!